# Getting invalid position on the array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am writing a program that reads a list of values, and 3 values, a, b, elem. I wrote a function which finds if the element is part of the array between the position a and b. When I run the program sometimes i get right results sometimes i get wrong results. I can't find the mistake. Any help would be welcomed.

```
int binary_search(int *v, int elem, int a, int b);

int main()
{
    printf("Inserire la lunghexza di N:\n");
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Inserire i valori dell'array:\n");
    int arr[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    int a,b,elem;
    printf("Inserire i valori di a, b, elem:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);
    scanf("%d", &elem);
    printf("%d", binary_search(arr,elem,a,b));
    return 0;
}

int binary_search(int *v, int elem, int a, int b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < i < b - a; i++) {
        if (*(v + a - 1 + i) == elem) {
            return a + i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the indention.

Comment: This line: `for (int i = 0; i < i<b-a; i++)` looks suspicious! Do you really mean: `for (int i = 0; i < b-a; i++)`??

Comment: it works as it should, just a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer already pointed out that the expression `i < i < b - a` in `for` loop condition is weird but it doesn't explain why?

```
for (int i = 0; i < i < b - a; i++)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

*Aren't you getting any compiler warning on this expression? If yes, one suggestion - warnings are there for some reason, don't ignore them.*

In the expression `i < i < b - a`, assume that `b - a` results in `x`. So, the expression `i < i < x` will be evaluated as `(i < i) < x` *(as the associativity of operator `<` is left to right)* in which `(i < i)` will always result in `false` and whole expression will always result in `true` for all valid<sup>**</sup> values of `a` and `b` which satisfy the condition `b > a` and if the `elem` value does not exists in array then due to this condition

```
if (*(v + a - 1 + i) == elem) {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

your program end up accessing array out of bound which is undefined behavior.

So, first of all correct the `for` loop condition by removing extra `i <`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b - a; i++)
```

Now, with this, the loop will check the values starting from `a`<sup>th</sup> element till `b - 1`<sup>th</sup> element in the array.

Also, following is more readable as compare to your current version of `binary_search()`:

```
int binary_search(int *v, int elem, int a, int b)
{
    for (int i = a - 1; i < b; i++) {
        if (v[i] == elem) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

There is another problem in your program - <sup>**</sup>your program is not checking the validity of user input `a` and `b`. It may be possible that user accidentally input the value of `a` and/or `b` which is not in the range of array or negative value or value of `a` greater than `b` etc. You should check the validity of user input as well.

PS: I assume that, you are very well aware of fact that, in your program, the `binary_search()` function is doing linear search and the binary search need the input array in sorted order.

Answer (score 2):

Like Adrian already pointed out, this line seems kind of weird:

```
for (int i = 0; i < i < b - a; i++)
```

Did you mean:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b - a; i++)
```